# how to get multiple result sets using linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have a stored procedure with around 14 different result sets. How do I retrieve them all as by now I only get the first result set.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("tire-tabel")]
public List<DeviationCalculation_Result> TireTabel(decimal presentWidth, decimal presentAspectRatio, string presentRimSize, int maxDeviation)
{
    using (var context = new OminiTireEntities())
    {
        var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<DeviationCalculation_Result>(
"exec [Tabel].[DeviationCalculation] @PresentWidth = '" + presentWidth + "', " +
"@PresentAspectRatio= '" + presentAspectRatio + "', " +
"@PresentInches= '" + presentRimSize + "', " +
"@MaxDeviation= '" + maxDeviation + "'").ToList<DeviationCalculation_Result>();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the code inside `[Tabel].[DeviationCalculation]`? You are passing few parameter values which I think gets into your `where` condition and returns you the filtered result?

Comment: not exactly it goes in to mathematical functions for calculating the circumference and then give back the deviation of 15 predefined circumference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample Code:

```
using (var db = new BloggingContext())
{
    // If using Code First we need to make sure the model is built before we open the connection
    // This isn't required for models created with the EF Designer
    db.Database.Initialize(force: false);

    // Create a SQL command to execute the sproc
    var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetAllBlogsAndPosts]";

    try
    {

        db.Database.Connection.Open();
        // Run the sproc 
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // Read Blogs from the first result set
        var blogs = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
            .ObjectContext
            .Translate<Blog>(reader, "Blogs", MergeOption.AppendOnly);   


        foreach (var item in blogs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }        

        // Move to second result set and read Posts
        reader.NextResult();
        var posts = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
            .ObjectContext
            .Translate<Post>(reader, "Posts", MergeOption.AppendOnly);


        foreach (var item in posts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Title);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        db.Database.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

The Translate method accepts the reader that we received when we executed the procedure, an EntitySet name, and a MergeOption. The EntitySet name will be the same as the DbSet property on your derived context. The MergeOption enum controls how results are handled if the same entity already exists in memory.

Reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj691402(v=vs.113).aspx

I also recommend to use Parameters instead of executing the queries as mentioned in the question as it **can result in SQL injection**

Answer (score 0):

With [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper) it is super simple:

```
public DeviationCalculationResult Get(decimal presentWidth, decimal presentAspectRatio, string presentRimSize, int maxDeviation)
{
    using (var context = new OminiTireEntities())
    {
        var reader = context.Database.Connection.QueryMultiple("[Tabel].[DeviationCalculation]",
            new
            {
                PresentWidth = presentWidth,
                PresentAspectRatio = presentAspectRatio,
                PresentInches = presentRimSize,
                MaxDeviation = maxDeviation
            }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        var first = reader.Read<First>().ToList().First();
        var second = reader.Read<Second>().ToList().First();
        var third = reader.Read<Third>().ToList().First();
        //...and so on...

        return new DeviationCalculationResult
        {
            First = first,
            Second = second,
            Third = third,
            //...
        };
    }
}
```