# How to do a Count() before a ToList() on records retrieved with a Stored Procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, ienumerable

Here's my code:

```
// grid query
var data = ctx.spRewards(Month, Year, null, MedicalID).Select(p => new
{
    MedicalID = p.MedicalID,
    DateReward = p.DateReward,
    Medical = p.Medical,
    AmountRefunds = p.AmountRefunds,
    AmountActivitiesStart = p.AmountActivitiesStart,
    AmountActivitiesEnd = p.AmountActivitiesEnd,
    AmountActivities = p.AmountActivities,
    AmountTotal = p.AmountTotal,
    Month = p.Month,
    Year = p.Year
});

// some further filters that will be attached in case

// grid order
data = data.OrderBy(p => p.DateReward).ThenBy(p => p.MedicalID);

// grid data
var dataTotal = data.Count();
if (formData.length >= 0)
{
    data = data.Skip(formData.start).Take(formData.length);
}
var dataFiltered = data.ToList();
return Json(new { data = dataFiltered, recordsFiltered = dataTotal, recordsTotal = dataTotal });
```

But once I try to do `var dataFiltered = data.ToList();`, I get a *The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once*.

My intent is to return just the count of records first (for get just the amount of filtered data, without download all records in memory and than Count, which would take time and resources), than paginate it with Skip/Take.

Usually this works using `IQueryable<a>` on tables:

```
var data = ctx.SomeTable.AsNoTracking().Select(p => new
{
    //
})
```

but it doesn't calling directly a Stored Procedure within the DB. I've tried to convert `data` from `IEnumerable<a>` to `IQueryable<a>` with `ctx.spRewards(Month, Year, null, MedicalID).AsQueryable()`, but I got the same error.

Somethings that I need to configure?

EDIT: added whole "actual" code suggested by answer, still not working:

```
var dataQuery = ctx.spRewards(Month, Year, null, MedicalID).AsQueryable().Select(p => new
{
    MedicalID = p.MedicalID,
    DateReward = p.DateReward,
    Medical = p.Medical,
    AmountRefunds = p.AmountRefunds,
    AmountActivitiesStart = p.AmountActivitiesStart,
    AmountActivitiesEnd = p.AmountActivitiesEnd,
    AmountActivities = p.AmountActivities,
    AmountTotal = p.AmountTotal,
    Month = p.Month,
    Year = p.Year
});

// grid - filters
string searchValue = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]")?.FirstOrDefault()?.ToLower();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
{
    dataQuery = dataQuery.Where(p =>
          p.Medical.ToLower().Contains(searchValue) ||
          p.AmountRefunds.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchValue) ||
          p.AmountActivitiesStart.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchValue) ||
          p.AmountActivitiesEnd.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchValue) ||
          p.AmountTotal.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchValue)
    );
}

// grid - order
string orderColumnId = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]")?.FirstOrDefault();
string orderColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" + orderColumnId + "][data]")?.FirstOrDefault();
string orderDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]")?.FirstOrDefault();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderColumn))
{
    if (orderDir == "desc")
    {
        dataQuery = dataQuery.OrderByDescending(orderColumn);
    }
    else
    {
        dataQuery = dataQuery.OrderBy(orderColumn);
    }
}
else
{
    dataQuery = dataQuery.OrderBy(p => p.DateReward).ThenBy(p => p.MedicalID);
}

    // grid - result
var dataClone = dataQuery.CloneQuery();
var dataTotal = dataQuery.Count();
if (formData.length >= 0)
{
    dataClone = dataClone.Skip(formData.start).Take(formData.length);
}
var dataFiltered = dataClone.ToList();
return Json(new { data = dataFiltered, recordsFiltered = dataTotal, recordsTotal = dataTotal });
```

EDIT 2: added spRewards definition:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<spRewards_Result> spRewards(Nullable<int> month, Nullable<int> year, Nullable<int> clinicID, Nullable<int> medicalID)
{
    var monthParameter = month.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("Month", month) :
        new ObjectParameter("Month", typeof(int));

    var yearParameter = year.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("Year", year) :
        new ObjectParameter("Year", typeof(int));

    var clinicIDParameter = clinicID.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("ClinicID", clinicID) :
        new ObjectParameter("ClinicID", typeof(int));

    var medicalIDParameter = medicalID.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("MedicalID", medicalID) :
        new ObjectParameter("MedicalID", typeof(int));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<spRewards_Result>("spRewards", monthParameter, yearParameter, clinicIDParameter, medicalIDParameter);
}
```

Comment: Why does `recordsFiltered` equal `recordsTotal`?

Comment: Noticed that as well.. I suspect it should be `recordsFiltered = dataFiltered.Length`.  Good spot on the Sproc and forward only. ;)

Comment: Because `spRewards` returns an `ObjectResult<T>`, it materializes the result at that point - so you are not filtering on the server anyway. You might as well just put a `ToList` immediately after the call to `spRewards`.

Comment: @NetMage so I need to download all the records to the memory even if i display later 10 with pagination? What if I have 1 billion records? Its a waste of resources. Can the sp be configured another way?

Comment: @NetMage question: if I convert SP to View, should this change? I.e. concatenate query to server than filter only at the last? Or won't change? Otherwise I think the only solution is to convert the sp to LINQ in sql notation (which is annoying).

Comment: It sounds like, since the sproc runs to completion on the server and returns the whole result, you could just add another sproc that only returns the count, and a third one that will return a subset of results for each page (which would have arguments specifying page size and page number)

Comment: @RufusL terrible :) At this point refactor the sp to LINQ as query notation would be even better...

Comment: I believe if you setup the SP as a View, you can use EF to query the view exactly like a table.

Comment: A different approach would be to create a function in SQL which counts the recordsand returns only the count value. Then query this function via LINQ and finally do the paging with calling+filtering your stored procedure. This way you're not querying the same resultset multiple times and hence don't get the error.

Comment: @Matt any practical example?

Comment: @markzzz - See the answer I added. It is easier without a separate function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is that you are using a stored procedure with Entity Framework, which creates a forward only result set.

Using an extension method, you can create a new query with the same conditions:

```
public static class IQueryableExt 
{
    public static IQueryable<T> CloneQuery<T>(this IQueryable<T> q) => q.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(q.Expression);
}
```

Then you can use the original query for the total count and the cloned query for the filtered records:

```
// grid data
var data2 = data.CloneQuery();
var dataTotal = data.Count();

if (formData.length >= 0)
{
    data2 = data2.Skip(formData.start).Take(formData.length);
}

var dataFiltered = data2.ToList();
```

Comment: Why I need this here with sp and not using ctx.SomeTable? Aren't both IQueryable<a>?

Comment: Because when you build a query expression around a stored procedure, any operation that executes against it will effectively execute the Stored Proc and from that point EF will interate. Running `Count` against an `IQueryble` against a DbSet will build and execute a `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM...` query, while the `ToList` will execute a separate query. With the Stored Proc the `Count` will execute the Sproc and iterate to get the count, meaning the later `Skip`/`Take`/`ToList` would be called against the results that are already iterated. If at all possible it is better to use the DbSets.

Comment: It is essentially a design decision in EF. I believe EF (not sure about Core) uses a DataReader against the result set from the Stored Procedure, which can only be iterated once. It is probably to prevent programmers from executing a stored procedure multiple times causing performance issues unintentionally.

Comment: @StevePy so, can I use DbSets with stored procedure? And get the same chain/results?

Comment: Anyway, tried your clone suggestion, but I get the same error "{"The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once."}". Sure is it correct? I've copy/paste the code...

Comment: Regarding A DbSet against a Stored Proc, no, it would need to be against a table or a view. Depending on what the Stored Procedure does, using the DbSet would mean building a Linq Query that reproduces the same rules as being done in the Stored Procedure against the applicable entities.

Comment: Be sure that the Clone result is stored in a different variable reference than the original query, then the count is executed against one, and the Skip+Take+ToList is executed against the 2nd clone. (I.e. `data.Count()` and `data2.Skip(..).Take(..).ToList()`)

Comment: Yes, as the example. I've did Copy and paste, as said. But still get the same error. What could be wrong? Do you Need the whole code?

Comment: @NetMage any clues?

Comment: I've added the actual whole code, so you can check its the same, still not working...

Comment: @markzzz How is `spRewards` actually defined?

Comment: @NetMage I've added the definition on the main topic. I've imported it with Visual Studio edmx manager, as usually.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to add a [`select @@ROWCOUNT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/564686/1016343) at the end of your SP and query the [2nd resultset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036662/how-to-get-multiple-result-sets-using-linq) (which then contains the rowcount).

As you can see in the link above, this can be achieved by calling
`reader.NextResult();`

That will switch the context of the reader to the next resultset. If you do that *without reading the 1st resultset,* there should be no row data transferred.

And if you just call it without advancing to the 2nd resultset, it returns the data from the stored procedure execution per default.

---

Example - [Northwind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/downloading-sample-databases) database.
Here we **create a new stored procedure** for demo purpose in the Northwind database, calling `[dbo][Employee Sales by Country]` and adding a 2nd resultset:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEmployeeSalesCount]  
    @Beginning_Date DateTime, @Ending_Date DateTime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- first resultset
    EXECUTE [dbo].[Employee Sales by Country] 
       @Beginning_Date,@Ending_Date

    -- 2nd resultset
    select @@ROWCOUNT as count
END
```

**Note:** You would just add `select @@ROWCOUNT as count` to the end of your existing stored procedure (SP), right after the last select that you want to return as data.
No need to create a 2nd SP in your production code, this is just for demonstration.

Now you want to get just the row count of GetEmployeeSalesCount based on the parameters being passed.

This is the C# code to retrieve the row count (you can run it in [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) - add and select a connection to the Northwind database):

```
// use LinqPad to try it out, connecting with the Northwind database
void Main()
{
    var conn = this; // in LinqPad, 'this' is the connection context

    var dtFrom = new DateTime(1998, 1, 1);
    var dtTo = new DateTime(1999, 1, 1);
    var count = GetSalesRowCount(conn.Connection, dtFrom, dtTo);
    Console.WriteLine($"Rowcount: {count}");

    // now you can do filtering based on the count value
    // This will read from the 1st resultset
    var skipNrRows = 260;
    var query = conn.GetEmployeeSalesCount(dtFrom, dtTo).AsDynamic()
                .Skip(skipNrRows).Take(count - skipNrRows);
    query.Dump();
}

int GetSalesRowCount(IDbConnection conn, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetEmployeeSalesCount]";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Beginning_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime) { Value = new DateTime(1998, 1, 1) });
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Ending_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime) { Value = new DateTime(1999, 1, 1) });
    cmd.Connection.Open();

    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    // this will read from the 2nd resultset
    reader.NextResult(); reader.Read();
    var count = (int)reader["count"];
    
    cmd.Connection.Close();
    
    return count;
}
```

It prints:

[image: query results]

---

**NOTE:** You could also access the 2nd resultset this way:

```
void Main()
{
    var conn = this; // in LinqPad, 'this' is the connection context

    var dtFrom = new DateTime(1998, 1, 1);
    var dtTo = new DateTime(1999, 1, 1);

    var queryForRS1 = conn.GetEmployeeSalesCount(dtFrom, dtTo);

    // Query row count before you run the query
    var queryForRS2 = queryForRS1.CreateDataReader();
    queryForRS2.NextResult(); queryForRS2.Read();
    var count = (int)queryForRS2.GetValue(0);
    count.Dump("Rowcount");

    // now use count and get the 1st resultset
    var skipNrRows = 260;
    var query = queryForRS1.AsDynamic()
                .Skip(skipNrRows).Take(count - skipNrRows);
    query.Dump("Query result"); 
}
```

Comment: Added 2nd way to query the 2 resultsets.